# Topology on a space starting from topologies on subspaces

Tags: general-topology

I have a question about constructing a topology on a space $X$ starting from topologies defined on a family of subspaces $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ of $X$.

Assume that $X$ is a set and $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ is a collection of subsets of $X$. Assume also that for every $i\in I$, there is a topology $\mathcal{T}_i$ defined on $X_i$. We say that a topology $\mathcal{T}$ on $X$ is consistent with the family $(X_i,\mathcal{T}_i)_{i\in I}$ if the induced topology by $\mathcal{T}$ on $X_i$ is exactly $\mathcal{T}_i$ for every $i\in I$. Consistent topologies may or may not exist. And if they exist, there might be a unique consistent topology, or there might be more than one. It is easy to check the following facts:

- If consistent topologies exist, then the finest consistent topology is given by $$\mathcal{T}=\{U\subset X:\; U\cap X_i\in\mathcal{T}_i,\;\forall i\in I\}.$$
- A necessary condition for the existence of consistent topologies is the pairwise compatibility of the topologies $(\mathcal{T}_i)_{i\in I}$, i.e., it must be the case that for every $i,j\in I$, the topology induced by $\mathcal{T}_i$ on $X_i\cap X_j$ must be the same as the topology induced by $\mathcal{T}_j$ on $X_i\cap X_j$.

The above condition becomes sufficient if the spaces $(X_i)_{i\in I}$ are an increasing sequence, i.e., if $I=\mathbb{N}$ and $X_n\subset X_{n+1}$ for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Is the above necessary condition also sufficient in general for arbitrary collection of subspaces? if not, is there a known necessary and sufficient condition for the existence of consistent topologies?

Is there a necessary and sufficient condition for the uniqueness of the consistent topology (in case such one exists)?

Has this problem been studied? If yes, can someone refer me to a good reference?

Comment: Well-asked question! It might be possible to construct three subspaces+topologies, that satisfy the pairwise consistency you describe, but nevertheless are not (three-way) consistent. If it is possible, it's probably possible to do so on a very small space, like fewer than 10 points.

Comment: have you looked at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct_limit and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coherent_topology ?

Comment: So the sequence condition can be generalised to being directed, e.g. which holds for most common cases. It would be nice if the directedness could be shown to be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but some steps along the way and too long for a comment:

Consider the collection of sets that you have already identified as the finest induced topology:
$$\mathcal T=\{U\subset X:\; U\cap X_i\in\mathcal T_i,\;\forall i\in I\}$$

It is fairly direct to show that regardless of the how the subspaces $X_i$ are chosen, $\mathcal T$ is a topology on $X$. If the $X_i$ cover $X$ and are severely in conflict with each other, then it may turn out that $\mathcal T$ is the trivial topology, but it is still a topology. And as you've noted, if there is any consistent topology, then this topology will be consistent.

So the question boils down to: when is this particular topology consistent? Is the condition $\mathcal T_i \mid_{X_i\cap X_j} = \mathcal T_j \mid_{X_i\cap X_j}$ for all $i,j$ sufficient?